# ColdFusion 8 - duplicate rows being inserted

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

This just started this morning.  A CFC I was working on yesterday, which does a simple insert into a table, started inserting duplicate rows (2 rows for each single insert).  I removed a bunch of extraneous code and simplified it and same thing.  So I moved just the cfquery to a separate page and just hard coded in 3 values - same thing - 2 rows inserted.  If I copy and paste the same query into mysql it works as expected - just one row inserted.  So I wrote a new simple query for a different table and it's happening there as well.

However - other pages/functions in our system are not doing this.  Just seemingly anything new I create or what I was working on yesterday and this morning.

The auto increment in MySQL is advancing, and I put a datetime column in and populate it with #now()# and that does show a slightly different timestamp between rows.  However - the CF debugger only shows the one insert query, even though CF seems to be firing it twice.

I've restarted the CF service and that hasn't helped.

Comment: Sharing some code with us would be useful. Also, checking in the repository/source control for what *may* have changed between yesterday and today by other team members would be a good idea (e.g. data access functions and helper methods).

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, *$#$^!~@! Firefox.

Something in browser seemed to be causing this.  I'll have to test further but switching browsers and everything is back to normal.

Comment: I'm thinking this isn't browser specific but *your* browser specific.  Did you try in firefox on another box?  I'm thinking perhaps a monitoring tool or something similar is firing it (like attempting to get the source for the page is executing it again, etc).  BTW, not a big firefox fan or anything, chrome user ;)

Comment: FF does start to misbehave after a full day's work if I'm using that.  It could have been something either Firebug or ColdFire was doing - sending a 2nd http request to the server for some reason.